# Will a transport agent execute before journaling occurs exchange 2013?

Tags: exchange-server, journaling, exchange-transport-agents, exchange-server-2013

I am currently working on proof of concept for a new system, but it is based on a transport agent executing before journaling takes place.

My question is: Will a transport agent that adds text to the subject of all messages occur before the journaling executes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the transport agent should execute before journalling occurs.